# Как менять местами блоки WP?

Tags: wordpress

учусь натягивать свою верстку на WP, верстаю секциями. Есть ли какой-то плагин или адекватный алгоритм действий, чтобы сделать возможность клиенту менять секции местами или отключать их из админки WP? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть плагины визуальных компоновщиков типа [Visual Composer](https://visualcomposer.io/) (бесплатный), его ветка [WP Bakery Visual Composer](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431) (платный), [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) (бесплатный с платными дополнениями).

Пока на рынке композеров лидирует WP Bakery Visual Composer, его активно догоняет Elementor и примерно через год может стать лидером.

В ближайшие месяцы выйдет WordPress 5.0, который будет штатно включать в себя Gutenberg - свой плагин визуальной компоновки. Как изменится после этого ситуация на рынке, предсказать сложно.